# htaccess unexpected parameter/change in url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

if i use a link in katalog:

```html
<a href="/katalog/musik">Musik</a>
```

It opens in the URL:

```
/katalog/musik/?&kategorie1=musik[NC,L]
```

and then the page.
But if I open /katalog/musik by myself in the URL the page open too.
The other rules are working fine, also with a .

How can I change it, that if I click on a link on a page, that the ?&... doesn't appear.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+) dienstleister.php?id=$3&kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+) kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+) kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: what do you what you link to look like?

Comment: Like /katalog/musik

Comment: just create a rule for that  link

Comment: `RewriteRule    ^/katalog/musik?$    kategorie.php    [NC,L]` if the page has a special `GET` variable add it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules and also add end anchor in last 3 rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ dienstleister.php?id=$3&kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2  [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm just getting now as URL `/katalog/musik/404`, but if I remove the 404 in the URL, it shows the right website.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302/404 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: I used Firefox to test this, there comes the result above. But if I use Chrome the URL is like I wished.

Comment: That means you have bad cache in Firefox. Completely clear cache and retest

Comment: Oh, doesn't knew that cache affect the URL too. Working now, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string to be discarded. This flag is available in Apache version 2.4.0 and later.

Add QSD to rewrites flags:

```
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+) dienstleister.php?id=$3&kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2 [NC,QSD,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+) kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1&kategorie2=$2  [NC,QSD,L]
RewriteRule ^katalog/([A-Za-z]+) kategorie.php?kategorie1=$1 [NC,QSD,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same result. The Apache Version ist 2.4.35, but the Server API is Apache 2.0 Handler. Is this relevant?